# Array size less than the no. of elements stored in it

Tags: arrays

Is it possible to declare an array of size 1 and be able to store 5 elements in it and then retrieve them?

I try one such code where I declared an array `arr[1]` and then stored 5 elements into it. It was actually possible to store 5 elements! How was it?

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: Depends on the programming language. So unable to give a definitive answer.

Comment: I think he is talking about C. For sure.

Answer (score 2):

If this is C (or C++), you can quite easily store more elements than the array is sized for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int x = 0;
    int a[1];    // so that a[0] is the only valid element
    a[1] = 7;    // write beyond end of array

    printf ("x=%d, &a[0]=%p, &a[1]=%p, &x=%p\n", x, &(a[0]), &(a[1]), &x);
    return 1;
}
```

Doing so, however, leads to undefined behaviour, probably overwriting some *other* piece of information, and is not really a good idea.

On my system, that code above prints:

```
x=7, &a[0]=0xbf9bb638, &a[1]=0xbf9bb63c, &x=0xbf9bb63c
```

despite the fact I set `x` to zero and never explicitly changed it. That's because writing beyond the end of the array has affected it (as you can see from the two identical addresses for `a[1]` and `x`).